# Resultado de MVC a Ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Estoy haciendo MVC en `php` junto a `js`. Dicho modelo contiene una consulta en `sql` el cual retorna un `json`, pasa por el controlador y luego al Ajax para asi manipular sus datos y mostrarlos en la Vista.

El problema viene dado (pienso yo) que es cuando el controlador devuelve el resultado hacia el archivo de Ajax. Si en el controlador aplico un `echo` o `var_dump()` y luego en el Ajax (success) un `console.log()` me muestra el resultado esperado. Si no aplico dicho `echo` o `var_dump()` el resultado simplemente es nada, no muestra nada. El cual pienso que sin los `echo` o `var_dump()` no retorna nada.

Mis codigos son lo siguiente:

**PHP:**

- ***Modules:***

  ```
  class Ajax
  {
      public $opcion;
      public $fecha;

      public function indicadoresAjax()
      {
          $datosAjax = array(
              "opcion" => $this->opcion,
              "fecha" => $this->fecha
          );

          $respuesta = Controller::indicadoresController($datosAjax);

      }
  }

  /*almaceno los valores de Ajax*/
  $ajax = new Ajax();
  $ajax->opcion = $_POST['opcion'];
  $ajax->fecha = $_POST['fecha'];
  $ajax->indicadoresAjax();
  ```
- ***Controlador:***

  ```
  class Controller
  {

      public static function indicadoresController($datosController)
      {

          $respuesta = Datos::indicadoresModel($datosController);

      }
  }
  ```
- ***Modelo:***

  ```
  class Datos extends conexion
  {
      public static function indicadoresModel($datosModel)
      {

              $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare($consulta);

              $stmt->execute();

              return json_encode($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));

              $stmt->closeCursor();

      }
  }
  ```

**Javascript/Jquery:**

- ***Ajax:***

```
$(".indicadores").change(function(){
    var opcion = $("#lista").val();
    var fecha = $("#primeraFecha").val();
        var datos = new FormData();

        datos.append("opcion", opcion); 
        datos.append("fecha", fecha);

        $.ajax({
            url: "views/modules/ajax.php",
            method:"POST",
            data: datos,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(respuesta){
                console.log(respuesta);
            }
        });
    });
```

Este es el resultado que espero sin necesidad de tener que aplicar un `echo` o `var_dump()` en mi controlador:

```
[{"BANCO":"100%BANCO (BU)","ACTIVOS_LIQUIDOS":"543455343","ACTIVOS_RENTABLES":"534354","PASIVOS_EXIGIBLES":"789879"....
```

Comment: En el controlador, pon esta línea `return $respuesta;` después de esta `$respuesta = Datos::indicadoresModel($datosController);` y comentas como te va.

Comment: @DjCrazy  también lo había pensado y al realizarlo simplemente el resultado es lo mismo, nada

Comment: El cuerpo de tu solicitud algo ha de tener y esto se logra imprimiendo por pantalla, ya tu mismo lo has comprobado, con la instrucción `return` no sale nada en el cuerpo de tu petición, sin embargo con un `echo` o `var_dump` si.

Comment: En algún punto debes hacer `echo`. Intenta esto... En el **Modelo** deja el `return` así `return $stmt->fetchAll();`. En el **Controlador** como te indiqué `return $respuesta;`. Finalmente, en **Modules** `echo json_encode($respuesta);`. Cabe recordarte hacer una copia de tus archivos antes de aplicar cualquier cambio en caso de que sea necesario revertirlos.

Comment: Otra cosa que puede estar pasando y aunque no estoy seguro, puedes descartar... usa siempre el mismo parámetro en **Modules**, **Controlador** y **Modelo**, es decir `($datosAjax)`

Comment: @DjCrazy aplique lo que dijiste anteriormente con los return y eso, imprime pero a la hora de manipular el `json` , es decir, `respuesta.forEach(e => console.log(e.BANCO));` (ejemplo), me sale `respuesta.forEach is not a function`

Comment: Ok, eso es un gran avance... si buscas mostrar solo la información de la columna **BANCO** prueba con esto: `console.log(respuesta['BANCO']);`.

Comment: @DjCrazy lo consegui cambiando de la manera que mencionaste y añadiendole `datatype: "json"` al `$.ajax` y para ingresar en los campos `console.log(respuesta[0].BANCO)`

Comment: Perfecto, puedes agregar la solución como una respuesta para que sirva de referencia a futuros visitantes. Digo, si así lo deseas!

Comment: @DjCrazy Listo, muchas gracias por la ayuda!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Llegue a una solución gracias a lo comentado por [@DjCrazy](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/40877/djcrazy)

1. En el **Modelo** deje el return, es decir, `return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`.
2. En el **Controlador** implementé `return $respuesta;`.
3. En **Modules** implementé `echo json_encode($respuesta);`.
4. En el `$.ajax` implementé `dataType: "json"`, eso significa que la solicitud espera una `json` de respuesta.
5. Apliqué un `console.log(typeof respuesta)` dentro del `success` de Ajax, para verificar si realmente era un objeto lo que obtenía (si era un objeto).
6. Para poder manipular dichos objetos, lo hice de la siguiente manera, primero accediendo a la posición y luego al campo, ya que si trato de ir directamente al campo `(respuesta.banco)` me sale un error.

El resultado al realizar dichos cambios fueron los siguientes:

- ***Modules:***

```
    class Ajax
    {
        public $opcion;
        public $fecha;

        public function indicadoresAjax()
        {
            $datosAjax = array(
                "opcion" => $this->opcion,
                "fecha" => $this->fecha
            );

            $respuesta = Controller::indicadoresController($datosAjax);

            echo json_encode($respuesta);

        }
    }

    $ajax = new Ajax();
    $ajax->opcion = $_POST['opcion'];
    $ajax->fecha = $_POST['fecha'];
    $ajax->indicadoresAjax();
```

- ***Controlador:***

```
class Controller
{
    public function plantilla()
    {
        include("views/template.php");
    }

    public static function indicadoresController($datosController)
    {

        $respuesta = Datos::indicadoresModel($datosController);
        return $respuesta;
    }
}
```

- ***Modelo:***

```
class Datos extends conexion
{
    public static function indicadoresModel($datosModel)
    {

            $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare($consulta);

            $stmt->execute();

            return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            $stmt->closeCursor();

    }
}
```

- ***Ajax:***

```
$.ajax({
            url: "views/modules/ajax.php",
            method:"POST",
            data: datos,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            dataType:'JSON',
            success: function(respuesta){
                   console.log(respuesta[0].BANCO);
            }
        });
```